# declare, condition, and return all on "one line"

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to write the inside of the following function as one line? I'd like to have a way to not have to declare `check`.

```
function Example {
    const check = this.readByUuidCheck(props)
    if (check) return this.readByUuid(check)
}
```

I'm looking for a way to minimize the duplication here:

```
function Example {
    const check = this.readByUuidCheck(props)
    if (check) return this.readByUuid(check)

    const alpha = this.alphaCheck(props)
    if (alpha) return this.alpha(alpha)

    const beta = this.betaCheck(props)
    if (beta) return this.beta(beta)

    const gamma = this.gammaCheck(props)
    if (gamma) return this.gamma(gamma)
}
```

Comment: I almost wonder if thats not a sort of anti-pattern? There is a great article called “Parse, don’t validate” (about user input), but I think my gut is saying something like “tell, don’t ask”—in other words, is there a way to eliminate the need for some kind of check/verification? It would be a race-condition in any non-single-threaded code anyway.

Comment: I'm trying to overload this example function with many different interface types. So in this case I think it makes sense for the check to have some kind of type guard. 

What do you mean by a race-condition in non-single threaded code?

Comment: Between the check and the execution of some function, someone else could cause the condition you just checked to be false. And now you call the function anyway, but under bad assumptions. There is a race of “who gets there first.” I’m not sure what you mean by overload with different interface types though

Answer (score 0):

I went with this abstraction:

```
function manage <T extends (...args: any) => any>(checker, method: T): (props:any) => ReturnType<T> {
  return (props: any) => { 
    const check = checker(props)
    if (check) return method(check)
    throw new Error('Unable to run')
  }
}

  function resolve(props:
    Props<ContactService['readById']> |
    Props<ContactService['readByUuid']> |
    Props<ContactService['readByUser']> |
    Props<ContactService['lookupOrUpsert']> |
    Props<ContactService['upsertOwnedByUser']> |
    Props<ContactService['handleCreateMemberArgs']> |
    Props<ContactService['handleCreateMemberArgsAlt']>
  ): Promise<[Contact, 'read' | 'create' | 'update' | null]> {
    return helper.compose.first(
      manage(this.readByIdCheck, this.readById),
      manage(this.readByUuidCheck, this.readByUuid),
      manage(this.readByUserCheck, this.readByUser),
      manage(this.lookupOrUpsertCheck, this.lookupOrUpsert),
      manage(this.upsertOwnedByUserCheck, this.upsertOwnedByUser),
      manage(this.handleCreateMemberArgsCheck, this.handleCreateMemberArgs),
      manage(this.handleCreateMemberArgsAltCheck, this.handleCreateMemberArgsAlt),
      helper.compose.error(new Error('unable to resolve contact'))
    )()
  }
```